# DHCP not starting CentOS 5.6

Tags: centos, dhcp-server

I am having a lot of trouble getting my dhcpd service to start on CentOS 5.6.

No matter what configuration I use it fails to start.

So I started looking around in the server, I noticed I have no file in `/sbin` named `dhcpd`, I do however have a file called `dhcp6c`.

That does not sound right though, is that a problem?

If that is not the problem, I don't what it is. I almost sure my config it good.

My /etc/dhcpd.conf:

```
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {

    option routers                  10.0.0.1;
    option subnet-mask              255.255.255.0;

    option domain-name              "solignis.local";
    option domain-name-servers      10.0.0.15;

    range   10.0.0.100      10.0.0.254;
    default-lease-time      86400;
    max-lease-time          172800;

}
```

** Update **

I found `dhcpd` it was in `/usr/sbin/`, so unless there is something wrong I am lost...

Here is my `ifconfig output`

```
[root@ns01 ns01]# /sbin/ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:A4:35:31  
          inet addr:10.0.0.15  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fea4:3531/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20639 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11293 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:25363968 (24.1 MiB)  TX bytes:874194 (853.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:3718 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3718 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4146173 (3.9 MiB)  TX bytes:4146173 (3.9 MiB)
```

Comment: How are you trying to start it, and what errors turn up in your logs?

Comment: Do you have a network interface in the 10.0.0.0/24 subnet?

Comment: Please, post your network configuration, ifconfig for example

Comment: I am starting the service with the Services GUI, and I also tried `/sbin/service dhcpd start` Both failed.

Comment: what error messages do you get (/var/log/messages) ?

Comment: That is just it, there are no errors, it just posts the version information for DHCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As root do a `which dhcpd`
That should state where the binary is located, otherwise a `yum search dhcpd` will show you what you seem to be missing, just install it.

Mostly... it's selinux. (Prevents the system from writing a .pid file for example.)

`setenforce 0` to disable it completely. It's defined in `/etc/selinux/config`
Try again

Be sure you keep an `tail -f /var/log/syslog` open at a terminal at all times ;)

Comment: What a surprise..... it was SELinux. Oh how I hate SELinux.